Does Australia and New Zealand have year round application system for PhD program in Mathematics?
I have completed my masters in mathematics from a institute in Asia. I will apply to Australia and New Zealand for PhD program in mathematics.

I wanted to know if Australia and New Zealand has a year round application system where I can write to professors year round or is there some specific months( Like November, December of each year) where I should write to them?

Please let me know

What do the policies at the school's you're looking at say? You could improve your question by doing some legwork before positing a question.
